# Flutter onTab Click Event Not Responsive

Tags: flutter, flutter-navigation

I am working on flutter footer navigation, I have a file where I initiate all parameters needed, like so:

```
  const Db5BottomNavigationBarItem({
    required this.icon,
    this.title,
    Widget? activeIcon,
    this.backgroundColor,
    required this.onTap,
  }) : activeIcon = activeIcon as String? ?? icon;

  
  final String icon;
  final String activeIcon;
  final Widget? title;
  final Color? backgroundColor;
  final Function onTap;
}
```

This is how I'm using it on my footer component:

```
 child: Db5BottomNavigationBar(
          items: <Db5BottomNavigationBarItem>[
            Db5BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: db5_ic_home,
              onTap: () {},
            ),
            Db5BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: db5_ic_heart,
              onTap: () {
                Navigator.push(context,
                    MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => new Health()));
              },
            ),
            Db5BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: db5_ic_msg,
              onTap: () {},
            ),
            Db5BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: db5_ic_setting,
              onTap: () {},
            ),
          ],
          // currentIndex: _selectedIndex,
          unselectedIconTheme: IconThemeData(color: db5_icon_color, size: 24),
          selectedIconTheme: IconThemeData(color: db5_colorPrimary, size: 24),
          onTap: (int index) {
            setState(() {
              // _selectedIndex = index;
            });
          },
          type: Db5BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
        ),
```

The problem is, once the button is clicked, let say the first:

```
                Navigator.push(context,
                    MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => new Health()));
              },
```

No error at all, and, no response.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What's the value of  db5_ic_home? Why are you using a type cast from Widget to String?

Comment: The value is 0, This is my code: var _selectedIndex=0; Db5BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: db5_ic_heart,
              onTap: () {
                Navigator.push(context,
                    MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => new Health()));
              }, ),                                                                                                                                                     currentIndex: _selectedIndex,
          onTap: (int index) {
            setState(() {
              _selectedIndex = index;
            }); },

Answer (score 1):

`BottomNavigationBarItem` does not have an `onTap` method, that's why nothing happens when you add code there. `BottomNavigationBar` itself has `onTap`, like in you code: `onTap: (int index)`. This will get called every time the user clicks on any item, and `index` will be 0,1,2 etc. based on position.

Reflecting the comments, I suggest using `BottomAppBar` as `bottomNavigationBar`, because the use case is navigation to a different route. Something like:

```
bottomNavigationBar: BottomAppBar(
  child: Row(
    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
    children: [
      TextButton(
        child: Column(mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min, children: [
          Icon(Icons.home),
          Text('Home'),
        ]),
        onPressed: () {
          Navigator.push(context,
            MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Route1()));
        },
      ),
      TextButton(
        child: Column(mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min, children: [
          Icon(Icons.message),
          Text('Message'),
        ]),
        onPressed: () {
          Navigator.push(context,
            MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Route2()));
        },
      ),
      TextButton(
        child: Column(mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min, children: [
          Icon(Icons.person),
          Text('User'),
        ]),
        onPressed: () {
          Navigator.push(context,
            MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Route3()));
        },
      )
    ],
  ),
))
```

To be complete, here is the same with `BottomNavigationBar`, but here is no new route, but existing widgets in `_pages`, and the `body` is replaced with one of them when something is selected. This way the navigation bar is persisting and showing current selection. But it also means that all the widgets in `_pages` are created and consuming memory.

```
class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  int _currentIndex = 0;

  static const List<Widget> _pages = <Widget>[
    Text('home'),
    Text('message'),
    Text('person'),
  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text("My App"),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: _pages.elementAt(_currentIndex),
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
        items: const <BottomNavigationBarItem>[
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.home),
            label: 'Home',
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.message),
            label: 'Message',
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.person),
            label: 'Person',
          ),
        ],
        currentIndex: _currentIndex,
        selectedItemColor: Colors.amber[800],
        onTap: (int index) {
          setState(() {
            _currentIndex = index;
          });
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I added, but I was getting errors. Can you extract how it is meant to be, I mean the codes? Thanks

Comment: Check the [example here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/BottomNavigationBar-class.html).

Comment: Like the other answer says, it is important to know whether you want to navigate to a different route and leave this one where the navigation bar is, or you'd like to keep it persistent and switch between existing widgets.

Comment: The color is fully selected, but, it not navigating

Comment: I want to navigate to a different route.

Comment: Ok, then I suggest something else, I will edit my answer.

Answer (score 0):

**BottomNavigationBarItem** doesn't have an onTap property.But you can give it an IconButton that has an onPressed parameter, instead of just assigning an icon.

```
BottomNavigationBarItem(
            label: 'Post',
            icon: IconButton(
                icon: Icon(Icons.add),
                onPressed: () => Navigator.push(context,
                    MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => CreatePage()))),
          )
```

.

```
bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
  ....
   onTap: (int index) {
   //Make sure you exclude the index of the Particular BottomNavigationBarItem you want to use the onTap on
          if (index != 2) {
            setState(() {
              _currentIndex = index;
            });
          }
```

This should be used if you want only one of your BottomNavigationBarItem to Route Somewhere. If your planing on using it on all the BottomNavigationBarItems as I saw on your Code, It will give you Routing Issues. You Should Use the `BottomNavigationBar OnTap` property with `currentindex`.

Comment: I want to navigate to each of the routes.

Comment: Here is an Example https://medium.com/@theboringdeveloper/common-bottom-navigation-bar-flutter-e3693305d2d